# HTTP Status 404 - Not Found Spring MVC RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring-mvc, annotations

I'm new to Spring Framework. I'm getting the following error. Please help in resolving it.

http://localhost:9090/FitnessTracker/addMinutes

HTTP Status 404 - Not Found

type Status report

messageNot Found

descriptionThe requested resource is not available.

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.2

Below is my web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>Fitness Tracker</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

below is my servlet-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.controller"></context:component-scan>
<!--    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/Views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>  -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" 
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/Views/" p:suffix=".jsp"/>
</beans>
```

Below is my MinutesController.java

```
package com.spring.bankApp.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class MinutesController {

    @RequestMapping("/addMinutes")
    public String addMinutes(){
        return "addMinutes";
    }

}
```

Below is my addMinutes.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Add Minutes</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Add Minutes Exercised</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that your «Views» directory has «V» in upper case ?

It may be the problem

Comment: yes. my folder name is correct and I have an other similar page which is working but not this.

Comment: Could you please provide a piece of code of a controller that works fine in your project ?

Comment: package com.spring.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

 @RequestMapping("/Hello")
 public String sayHello(Model model){
  model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hello World");
  return "Hello";
 }
}

Comment: above comment has the controller class code which is working fine

Comment: «Hello.jsp» and «addMinutes.jsp» are in the same directory, with the correct case ?

Comment: yes. they are in same directory and the filenames are correct.

Comment: I deleted the MinutesController.java file and re-created the same file then it started working I'm not sure what was the problem previously. but anyway thanks :)